# writing function using varargin and varargout

Tags: matlab, function

I have this function and I want to use varargin and varargout for all the inputs and the outputs and I don't know exactly how to do it.

Any suggestions? This is my function:

```
function [Output0,Output1] = myfunction(p0,p1,normal0,normal1,c0,c1)

t0 = sqrt((c0^2)/((normal0(1)^2) + (normal0(2)^2) + (normal0(3)^2)));
Output0= p0 + normal0*t0;

t1 = sqrt((c1^2)/((normal1(1)^2) + (normal1(2)^2) + (normal1(3)^2)));
Output1= p1 + normal1*t1;
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you sure you want `varargin`? That allows you any number of inputs. It looks like you have a defined number of possible inputs and so you might find that just using `nargin` is more suitable. Or is you just want to make it handle `n` dimensions, then rather vectorize. Instead of x0 and x1 you could just have `X` or instead of `x0`, `y0` and `z0` you could just have `P0`...

Comment: instead of x0,y0 and z0 I will have p0. But and the same for the x1,y1 and z1. but what I want is to make the input and the out put variables so I could use it with another variables because I have two functions exactly the same as this one but with different variable input and output names.

Comment: @Jack_111 What will be the benefit of it? The variable names of the parameters (i.e., in the function definition) and of the arguments (i.e., in the call) are independent of each other. You can call this function happily with `[o1, o2] = myfunction(foo0, foo1, no0, no1, c00, c01)` if your variables are named this way.

Comment: I want to use varargin and varargout in it (because I have each function 3 times but with different input and output names). It is now kind of practicing because I have to implement it in another functions that I have.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think this is an appropriate case for `varargin` or even for `nargin`. This is a case for vectorizing your function.

OK so lets say you have these inputs: xo, yo, zo, x1, y1, z1 (all scalar), normal0 (1x3), normal1 (1x3) and c0 and c1 both scalar.

Lets see if we can vectorize your function to calculate all the outputs in one shot. So first we'll rearrange your data:

```
P = [x0, x1;
     y0, y1
     z0, z1];

N = [normal0;
     normal1]'; %better here to just make normal0 a (3x1) so no need to transpose

C = [c0, c1]
```

now lets look at how you got your first output:

```
t0 = sqrt((c0^2)/((normal0(1)^2) + (normal0(2)^2) + (normal0(3)^2)));
Output0= p0 + normal0*t0;
```

this can be simplified to

```
p0 + normal0 * sqrt(c0^2/sum(normal0.^2))
```

which can be generalized to

```
P + bsxfun(@times,N,sqrt(bsxfun(@rdivide,C.^2,sum(N.^2))))
```

So now you get any number of outputs in one shot! In one line too!

Just a quick explanation of where `bsxfun` came into it. So in your original calcs you sometimes multiply or add a scalar to a vector. Matlab allows this but it doesn't allow the higher dimensional case of say adding a vector to a 2D matrix. `bsxfun` does this for us. so where I have `bsxfun(@times, N, B)` above, it just takes the 3x1 `B` vector and does an elementwise multiplication (`@times` is the function handle to `.*`) of `B` on each column of the 3x2 `N`. But here it's fine for N to be 3xX i.e. have any number of columns i.e. any number of inputs.